# Question on Viruses

Tags: homework, virology

> A recent study has provided evidence that two types of equine (horse) herpes viruses have an unusually broad host range. This fact supports which of the following statements?
>
> a. The lytic cylce occurs in horses while the lysogenic cycle occurs only in other species.
>
> b. The virus is transmitted from one host to another by mosquitoes.
>
> c. In a population of horses, many of the individuals will become infected
>
> d. Horses, rhinoceroses, and polar bear can become infected
>
> e. In an individual horse, many different type of cells will be infected

According to the answer key, the answer is D. My question is why isn't E also a correct answer? I thought host range means "the range of cells that can act as a host to a virus".

Comment: A host is an organism, not a cell of an organism.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please do not just upload images but make the effort to rewrite the text. Images are not searchable and is a trouble for people with visual impair. Also, your title is not helpful. Of course the post will contain a question, so it is useless to use the word question in the title. Try to be more specific.

Comment: You must provide text for questions otherwise they will be removed as they cannot be indexed properly. A scan is not acceptable.

Comment: I think this is a good question because it highlights a critical pitfall in any field of science: making broad assumptions with too little or poor data. It also in part highlights poor test questions/mentoring that lead people into these pitfalls. See in my comments on Yordan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

"host" refers to the organism as a whole. So `two types of equine herpes viruses have an unusually broad host range` means here that these two viruses have the particular ability to infect various animals, and not only horses.

Comment: And yet that statement *still* doesn't support any of the possible answers. Is that a fussy assumption?

Comment: @CMosychuk My guess is that the question is badely put. It should have been more like 'Based on this fact, which of the following statements can be considered as true?'. Then d. is the correct answer because the fact that these viruses have a broad host range is enough to explain why polar bear and rhinos can also be infected. However, it is kind of a circular reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is D and there is nothing wrong with the question. @user34748, the very **definition** of host range is the range of **species** a virus can infect, **not** cell types. See the Wikipedia **definition of host** as used in biology: [In biology, a host is an **organism** that harbors a parasitic, a mutual, or a commensal symbiont, typically providing nourishment and shelter.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_(biology))  This is why the answer is D, not E. If the question specified **host cell types**, then E would have been the correct answer.

The problem is that you are **supposed** to know the definition before you go to exam and host has very clear definition in parasitology in general as the **organism** the infectious  organism infects, **not** its cell types! In fact if the answer was to be E the very structure of the question had to be changed to include a special close specifying it is host cell types, not the hosts themselves the question is about. And this is clearly not the case here. This is why the answer is D, not E. Even from a testological point of view there is nothing wrong with the question. The methodology used to compose it is within the limits of what you are expected to know and the reasoning you are expected to be able to use. It's legitimate virology question.

Comment: As I understand it, the correct answer is that multiple species (polar bear, rhino, horse) can get infected because these viruses have a broad host range. But I guess that the very definition of having a broad host range is being able to infect various hosts. So, in the end the reason why d. is correct is that d. is correct...

Comment: No, the reason why D is correct is because you definition you should have known before entering this exam is " In biology, a host is an organism that harbors a parasitic, a mutual, or a commensal symbiont, typically providing nourishment and shelter." If you knew this definition, you should not have had any problems choosing D as answer. See definitions are **important** in biology, if you don't pay enough attention to them you can easily make mistakes later on in both interpreting and even noticing important tendencies in your data. You should have paid attention to the definition of host!

Comment: Basically the entire question revolves around knowing or not what the definition of **host** is in virology. If you have considered that host is always an **organism** and **not** just a single cell you would never had failed the question and ask it here. I advise you the next time you go take a test-learn your **definitions** better. Hope you make good lesson out of this experience.

Comment: Well, I did not *fail* the question, because I did not *take* the exam. I'm not the OP, I'm just confused by the way the question is asked. And for that matter, I am well aware that definitions are important in biology, as in every other field of science.

Comment: On Northwestern University's website in states that the definition of a host range is, "The range of cells that can act as a host to a virus or bacteriophage." So according to what you are saying, this definition is wrong? http://groups.molbiosci.northwestern.edu/holmgren/Glossary/Definitions/Def-H/host_range.html

Comment: I'm very sorry @Flo for taking you for the OP instead of the editor, I just didn't see it. Sorry again. Now I looked at the link you provided and this is what is says: 1. The spectrum of strains of bacterial species that a given strain of phage can infect. 
 2. The range of cells that can act as a host to a virus or bacteriophage.

Comment: It isn't "wrong" per se, but just more **specific**. It is designed specially for bacteriophages, not for host range in general. In the case of bacteriophages the cell **is** the organism, so one doesn't need to add anything more specific to understand any difference between a cell and an organism. In this case there is no need to specify any cell types. However, the OP's question has a possible answer **specifying** cell types, therefore, the lecturer should haven't ever used such definition for his/hers course or otherwise this questions would indeed have been wrong to ask.

Comment: Then my arguments is: Did the lecturer in the OP's course used the definition you provided or did s/he used the broad definition of a host in parasitology? If s/he indeed used the definition you provided the question was indeed wrong to ask. However, if s/he didn't used this definition, but one similar to the broad parasitological definition, then it's the OP's fault to have failed the question. Do you know what definition the lecturer of the class used or even what was the class about?

Comment: Without explicitly demonstrating the virus in a polar bear or rhinoceros, how would the statement "a virus has more than one host species" lead you to assume a polar bear or a rhinoceros can be infected? Why not bobcats or barn owls? *That* requires more data than this question provides, and here's the actual paper being referenced ([1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24440374), [2](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/11/151102083246.htm)). You can see how *they* can make that assumption, QED.

Comment: @CMosychuk , still the OP should have known the definition of a virus in parasitology and should have thought out the question carefully. If s/he drew on the information provided in the question and what s/he was supposed to know is a host range, s/he wouldn't have made the mistake. There is enough information provided in the question to come to the right answer.